# At what point I need to do Dispose of my custom WPF User Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dispose

My question is about memory handling in WPF. I have created a user control with notрing but XAML witch contains only standard WPF controls. I didn't implement any code in code-behind at this point.

In my application, I create an instance of this user control to display to a user. When I no longer need the user control, I can just assign it's reference variable a null value.

Do I need to write a .Dispose method myself and dispose inner controls in my user control? Or is it a good practice to leave this job to a garbage collector? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, in WPF, you don't need to make your controls `IDisposable`.  Unlike Windows Forms, WPF `UIElement` objects are completely managed, and not (normally) wrapping native handles.  As such, they don't need to be disposed, and can be left to the garbage collector.

This is why `UserControl` does not implement `IDisposable`.

There are, of course, exceptions.  If your class encapsulates anything deriving from [`HwndHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost.aspx) (such as WebBrowser), for example, you will likely want to make your class `IDisposable` in order to call `Dispose()` on the encapsulated control.  This is normally only required in interop scenarios (ie: `WebBrowser`, which interops with the native browser controls).

Comment: Does that mean that dropping a lot of textboxes (or whatever the WPF equivalent is) on a form does not consume a lot of handles?

Comment: @Lasse: One of the huge advantages of WPF is that a Window with 1000 textboxes uses 1 handle - the Window's handle.  Everything internal is rendered via Direct3D within a single HWND.  Each TextBox does not use a separate handle in WPF, unlike Windows Forms.  (There are some rare exceptions - I edited to explain...)